# JQM How to remove DOM of the previous page with changepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dom

I'm currently have an issue with my code.

When I call the changepage method on jquery mobile, my page stay in the dom.

I want to remove that, but I didn't find the answer on internet and stackoverflow.

I tried to $().remove() manually my page, but when I keep back into the page, it doesn't display anything.

Anyone have the solution ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This may fix your issue:

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').on('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  $(ui.prevPage).remove();
});
```